# Handlebars template engine with Bootstrap on Yeoman

Tags: sass, handlebars.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, yeoman, assemble

I'm using Yeoman with the Bootstrap generator (updated to SASS). Is there any way to incorporate the Handlebars template engine to work with those? I'm not looking to use either Ember or Backbone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Assemble to handle my Handlebars templating. This is a good article (4 parts) about getting Assemble set up with your Yeoman/Grunt setup:

http://www.gpmd.co.uk/blog/front-end-process-flat-builds-and-automation-part-1-introduction/

Here is the Assemble site/documentation:

http://assemble.io/

Comment: Thanks, will definitely have a look at this.